# Make grunt to run from "dest" and expose it via IP

Tags: ip, port, gruntjs

I am new to using Grunt build tool. Suppose if I already have the required files in my "dest" folder how can I use Grunt to simply load the same to the server.
Also, I am currently able to access grunt service running on "localhost" on 9090 port.
But if I replace the "localhost" with my ip address, I am getting a 404.
I tried the same with my tomcat server but I am able to access the tomcat server on 8080 port via IP address as well. Please let me know what needs to be done to allow access via IP? I am using a Windows PC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case someone stumbles upon this one, just change localhost to 0.0.0.0 in the gruntfile.

This is the reference: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/commit/fbad1ab0ab789bb37fe5dfa40d5e8ada2f4fa0c5

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking about how to copy files to a remote server using Grunt.

If so try either [grunt-ssh](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ssh) if you have SFTP/SCP acceess to your remote server, or [grunt-ftp-deploy](https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy) if you only have FTP access.

Comment: No this is with respect to replacing "localhost" with the device IP address which fails.

Comment: I have a similar issue.  I am using php as the web server for my dev project, and I cant get to the page I am developing from my iPad via my computers ip address.  My project only works via the local machine at localhost:9000.  What Gives?